# Purpose of first 64KB of Btrfs partition

Tags: btrfs

Does Btrfs use the first 64KB of the partition for data? If not, then what is its significance? I have ran various experiments with it and found that it remains unused even when partition is filled to capacity.

Answer (score 1):

**No, Btrfs does not use this area for data. This is a bootloader area.** Chris Mason, the principal Btrfs author, explained it [in his answer](http://www.mail-archive.com/linux-btrfs@vger.kernel.org/msg20470.html) to the following question (I added [few remarks] and `code formatting` for readability):

> > When creating a btrfs volume with `mkfs.btrfs`, I'm noticing that the first 64KB are completely blank. Is this gap expressly intended for installing a boot manager/loader? e.g. GRUB 2 allows installation of `boot.img` + `core.img` into a btrfs formatted partition, without using block lists (the `--force` flag). It appears to produce a bootable system.
>
> Right, I wanted to leave room for bootloaders. I actually would have
>   used a larger offset, but the other filesystem `mkfs` commands don't zero
>   very far into the drive. I had to make sure that `mkfs.foo` would
>   overwrite the btrfs super[block], otherwise you might have a stale btrfs
>   filesystem recognized inside the new filesystem.
>
> […]
>
> -chris [Mason]